# pcl coordinate system orientation

Tags: ros, coordinate-system, pcl, ros-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am aware that ros uses the positive coordinate system in which x=forward, y=left, and z=up, but can anyone tell me what pcl data uses?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55955/pcl-coordinate-system-orientation/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-22**:
joq, that's what I thought until I used the function pcl::fromROSMsg() and a pcl passthrough filter.  The PCL z parameter pertained to forward direction and y pertainted to the upward direction.  I'm speaking in terms of the pcl namespace.  Is this correct?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-23**:
Check the `header.frame_id` field in the message. It may be using an "optical" frame by mistake. See: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#coordinate-frame-conventions

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-23**:
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same, in whatever frame of reference the PointCloud2 message specifies.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1